# Batching in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Very new to nodejs, I have a file which contains only single column `jobid`. And I am iterating one by one job id and sending requesting to a service which give me the status of the job in a `json` format. Reading the `json` response and fetching few values from it and writing to the database. And I want write when it reach the 100th(with the help of a counter) `jobid`(because I am expecting more than 100 `jobid` in the file, also this is dynamic).

For example if I have 234 records, then it will write 3 times, first two 100 each and third one with 34. And the `jobStatusMetrics` array should be cleaned every write.

```
const fileStatusprocess = require('../controller/readResultFile');
const config = require('../config/config');
const https = require('https');
const uuid = require('uuid-random');

async function jobProcesser() {
    const iterator = (await fileStatusprocess.processResultFile("C:\Support\result.csv"))
    console.log('Total jobs are',iterator[0].length);
    var counter = 0 ;
    for (i = 0; i < iterator[0].length; i++) {
        counter++;
        const formJobStatusURL = "https://localhost:8091/api/job/" + iterator[0][i] + "/status";
        
        const option = {
            method: 'GET' ,
            headers: {
                'X-Message-Created-Ts': `${new Date().toISOString()}`,
                'X-Transaction-Created-Ts': `${new Date().toISOString()}`,
                'X-User-Id': 'PerformanceExecuter',
                'X-Client-Id': `${uuid()}`,
                'X-Message-Id': `${uuid()}`,
                'X-Transaction-Id': `${uuid()}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        let content = '';
        let reqGet = https.request(formJobStatusURL,option, function (response) {
            response.on('data', function (data) {
                content += data;
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                const jsonPayload = JSON.parse(content);
                const jobStatusMetrics = {};
                for ( var key in jsonPayload){
                    if(jsonPayload.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                        jobStatusMetrics.job_id = jsonPayload.id;
                        jobStatusMetrics.status = jsonPayload.status;
                        jobStatusMetrics.initiatedBy = jsonPayload.initiatedBy;
                        jobStatusMetrics.product = jsonPayload.product;
                        jobStatusMetrics.operation = jsonPayload.operation;
                        jobStatusMetrics.startTimestamp = jsonPayload.startTimestamp;
                        jobStatusMetrics.endTimestamp = jsonPayload.endTimestamp;
                        jobStatusMetrics.totalRecords = jsonPayload.file.totalRecords;
                        jobStatusMetrics.failedRecords = jsonPayload.file.totalFailedRecords;
                        jobStatusMetrics.sucessRecords = jsonPayload.file.totalSuccessRecords;
                        jobStatusMetrics.inprogressRecords = jsonPayload.file.totalInProgressRecords;
                        jobStatusMetrics.sucessStatus = jsonPayload.results.successFileAvailable;
                        jobStatusMetrics.failureStatus = jsonPayload.results.failureFileAvailable;
                        jobStatusMetrics.uploadJob = jsonPayload.actionsAvailable.dataUploadAllowed;
                        jobStatusMetrics.abortJob = jsonPayload.actionsAvailable.abortJob;
                    }
                    if ( counter%100 == 0) {
                        console.log('Writting to the database')
                        // logic for influxdb writter
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                }
                //console.log(jobStatusMetrics);
            })
        });
        reqGet.end();
   
    }
}

jobProcesser()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather to use `https` for http request please use another library like `phin-retry`. Please check the below code, added the logic. Hope this work.

```
const rp = require('phin-retry');
const fileStatusprocess = require('../controller/readResultFile');
const config = require('../config/config');
const uuid = require('uuid-random');
const influxDBWrite = require('../controller/influxdbWritter')


async function checkFileStatus() {
    const iterator = (await fileStatusprocess.processResultFile("C:\Support\result.csv"));
    const jobIds = iterator[0];
    console.log(jobIds)
    let jobDetailsList = [];
    for (i = 0; i < jobIds.length; i++) {
        console.log('JobId', i)
        const jobId = jobIds[i];
        const formJobStatusURL = "https://localhost:8091/api/job/" + jobId + "/status";
        const jobDetails = await rp.get({
            url: formJobStatusURL,
            headers: {
                'X-Message-Created-Ts': `${new Date().toISOString()}`,
                'X-Transaction-Created-Ts': `${new Date().toISOString()}`,
                'X-User-Id': 'PerformanceExecuter',
                'X-Client-Id': `${uuid()}`,
                'X-Message-Id': `${uuid()}`,
                'X-Transaction-Id': `${uuid()}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        jobDetailsList.push(jobDetails);
        if ((i + 1) % 5 === 0) {
            await saveResultsToInfux(jobDetailsList);
            jobDetailsList = [];
        } 
    }
    await saveResultsToInfux(jobDetailsList);

}

async function saveResultsToInfux(jobDetailsList) {
    const metrics = [];
    for (i = 0; i < jobDetailsList.length; i++) {
        console.log('Metrics', i)
        const jobDetail = jobDetailsList[i];
        const tags = {
            Id: jobDetail.id,
            Status: jobDetail.status.overall,
            Product: jobDetail.product,
            Entity: jobDetail.entity,
            Operation: jobDetail.operation
        }
        const fields = {
            startTimestamp:jobDetail.startTimestamp,
            endTimestamp:jobDetail.endTimestamp,
            totalRecords:jobDetail.file.totalRecords,
            totalFailedRecords:jobDetail.file.totalFailedRecords,
            totalSuccessRecords:jobDetail.file.totalSuccessRecords,
            totalInProgressRecords:jobDetail.file.totalInProgressRecords,
            successFileAvailable:jobDetail.results.successFileAvailable,
            failureFileAvailable:jobDetail.results.failureFileAvailable,
            dataUploadAllowed:jobDetail.actionsAvailable.dataUploadAllowed,
            abortJob:jobDetail.actionsAvailable.abortJob,
        }
        metrics.push({
            measurement: 'BulkData',
            tags,
            fields
        });
    }
    influxDBWrite.dbWritter(metrics);
}
checkFileStatus()
```